# Attempted import error: 'useSwiper' is not exported from 'swiper/react/swiper-react'

Tags: reactjs, import, next.js, importerror, swiper.js

I am using SwiperJS in Next.js and trying to set up custom navigation. I want to use the useSwiper hook as explained in the docs (https://swiperjs.com/react#use-swiper) but the import is not working.

When trying to import the hook;
`import {Swiper, SwiperSlide, useSwiper} from 'swiper/react/swiper-react'` i am running in to error `Attempted import error: 'useSwiper' is not exported from 'swiper/react/swiper-react'.`

I have checked the swiper-react.js file and as far as i can see it does export the useSwiper hook;

```
import { Swiper } from './swiper.js';
import { SwiperSlide } from './swiper-slide.js';
export { useSwiperSlide, useSwiper } from './context.js';
export { Swiper, SwiperSlide }
```

The Swiper and SwiperSlide imports are working fine.

Unsure as to why this is happening if anyone can please help?

Comment: `.node_modules/swiper/package.json` has an `exports` field which defines the package's allowable imports. It has a `"./react"` key which resolves to the module path `./react/swiper-react.js`. What happens if you `import { useSwiper} from "swiper/react"` (sans the trailing `/swiper-react`)?

Comment: import { useSwiper } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react' - this is working now for some reason? I don't know if you have to restart npm run dev for it to work and maybe I didn't restart npm run dev yesterday when I was trying?